# ValueError: Input contains NaN, ... when doing fit_transform() in BERTopic

Tags: python, machine-learning, bert-language-model

I want to make BERTopic model with my clustering algorithm (KMeans) and my Vectorizer (Count Vectorizer), but I keep getting this warning and error when I want to do .fit_transform(data) :

Warining:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bertopic/vectorizers/_ctfidf.py:69: RuntimeWarning:

divide by zero encountered in divide
```

And then, error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-1f024d22018f> in <module>
----> 1 topics, probs = bert_topic_model.fit_transform(final_df.body)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bertopic/_bertopic.py in fit_transform(self, documents, embeddings, y)
    368             self._map_representative_docs(original_topics=True)
    369         else:
--> 370             self._save_representative_docs(documents)
    371 
    372         self.probabilities_ = self._map_probabilities(probabilities, original_topics=True)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bertopic/_bertopic.py in _save_representative_docs(self, documents)
   3000                 bow = self.vectorizer_model.transform(selected_docs)
   3001                 ctfidf = self.ctfidf_model.transform(bow)
-> 3002                 sim_matrix = cosine_similarity(ctfidf, self.c_tf_idf_[topic + self._outliers])
   3003 
   3004                 # Extract top 3 most representative documents

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py in cosine_similarity(X, Y, dense_output)
   1178     # to avoid recursive import
   1179 
-> 1180     X, Y = check_pairwise_arrays(X, Y)
   1181 
   1182     X_normalized = normalize(X, copy=True)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
     62             if extra_args <= 0:
---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     64 
     65             # extra_args > 0

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py in check_pairwise_arrays(X, Y, precomputed, dtype, accept_sparse, force_all_finite, copy)
    144                             estimator=estimator)
    145     else:
--> 146         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=accept_sparse, dtype=dtype,
    147                         copy=copy, force_all_finite=force_all_finite,
    148                         estimator=estimator)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
     62             if extra_args <= 0:
---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     64 
     65             # extra_args > 0

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    648     if sp.issparse(array):
    649         _ensure_no_complex_data(array)
--> 650         array = _ensure_sparse_format(array, accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
    651                                       dtype=dtype, copy=copy,
    652                                       force_all_finite=force_all_finite,

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _ensure_sparse_format(spmatrix, accept_sparse, dtype, copy, force_all_finite, accept_large_sparse)
    446                           % spmatrix.format, stacklevel=2)
    447         else:
--> 448             _assert_all_finite(spmatrix.data,
    449                                allow_nan=force_all_finite == 'allow-nan')
    450 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, msg_dtype)
    101                 not allow_nan and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
    102             type_err = 'infinity' if allow_nan else 'NaN, infinity'
--> 103             raise ValueError(
    104                     msg_err.format
    105                     (type_err,

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

This is my full code:

```
features = final_df["body"] # does not have NaN or Infinite values, I have checked 10 times
transformerVectoriser = CountVectorizer(analyzer = 'word', ngram_range = (1, 4), vocabulary = vocab_list)
#my vocab list does not have NaN or Infinite values, I have checked 10 times

cluster_model = KMeans(n_clusters = 50, init='k-means++', max_iter = 1500, random_state=None)

bert_topic_model = BERTopic(hdbscan_model = cluster_model, 
                            vectorizer_model = transformerVectoriser, 
                            verbose = True, 
                            top_n_words = 15)

#final_df.body does not have NaN or Infinite values, I have checked 10 times
topics, probs = bert_topic_model.fit_transform(final_df.body) #ERROR
```

I really do not know what is the problem, and what is going on.
All values in vocab_list are string values and all values in final_df.body are string values

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps to explicitly cast the series to the required data type, before using it in `fit_transform`. It should at least help to identify the problem:

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.to_numeric(final_df.body)
```

so your code would look like this:

```py
features = final_df["body"] # does not have NaN or Infinite values, I have checked 10 times
transformerVectoriser = CountVectorizer(analyzer = 'word', ngram_range = (1, 4), vocabulary = vocab_list)
#my vocab list does not have NaN or Infinite values, I have checked 10 times

cluster_model = KMeans(n_clusters = 50, init='k-means++', max_iter = 1500, random_state=None)

bert_topic_model = BERTopic(hdbscan_model = cluster_model, 
                            vectorizer_model = transformerVectoriser, 
                            verbose = True, 
                            top_n_words = 15)

pd.to_numeric(final_df.body)
#final_df.body does not have NaN or Infinite values, I have checked 10 times
topics, probs = bert_topic_model.fit_transform(final_df.body) #ERROR
```